# Scraping several websites with the loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

in the following code, I created a function for a web scrape. The next step I want to do is:

1. create a loop which scrapes through links provided in the areas_links
2. saves it to the data frame with the name from areas tuple.

Naturally, I could do everything separately but that's not the point in this exercise.

```
# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from IPython import display  

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

areas_links =  ('https://www.morizon.pl/ceny/warszawa/',
      'https://www.morizon.pl/ceny/warszawa/bemowo/')

areas = ('warszawa','bemowo')

def web_scrape(url):
    # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    # find a string starting from generatechartData
    data = soup.find(string=re.compile('generatechartData()'))
    # finding patter for Price
    pattern = '\r?\ndescription: "([^"]+)"(?:\r?[^()]+)\)'
    rPrices = re.findall(pattern, data) 
    # finding patter for date
    pattern = '\r?(?:\r?\n(?!newDate\.setFullYear\().*)*\r?\nnewDate\.setFullYear\(([^()]+)\);'
    rdates = re.findall(pattern, data)
    # removal of '\n' in the data
    rdates = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in rdates]
    # split dates on Years and Months 
    rYear = [i.split(',')[0] for i in rdates] 
    rMonth = [i.split(',')[1] for i in rdates] 
    # data cleaning on the December. For some reason its '0' instead of '12'
    rMonth = [re.sub(r'\b0\b', '12', i) for i in rMonth]
    #building dataframe for the data
    df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Prices': rPrices,
     'Year': rYear,
     'Month': rMonth
     })

for i in areas_links:
web_scrap(i)
```

Comment: and what you expect from us? You didn't say what is wrong. If you got error message then show it in question (not in comment) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run it to see error. And if code works and you expect to review code then go to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), PL: i czego od nas oczekujesz? Nie powiedziałeś co jest nie tak z kodem. Jeśli dostajesz komunikat o błędzie to pokaż go w pytaniu (nie w komentarzu) jako tekst (nie jaki zdjęcie). A jeśli oczekujesz aby ktoś przejrzał kod to idź na [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: inside function you use `urlpage` but you have `def web_scrap(url)` - you have to change name `url` to `urlpage`. And you forgot `return df` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expected because most of your code works and it runs with urls from `areas_links` and it gives `df` which you have to only save (with different names)

In `def web_scrap(url)` you have to use variable `urlpage` instead of `url` and you have to use `return df` at the end.

And then loop works. It gives `df` which you can save in separated files.

```
areas_links =  ('https://www.morizon.pl/ceny/warszawa/',
      'https://www.morizon.pl/ceny/warszawa/bemowo/')

areas = ('warszawa','bemowo')
    
for url, name in zip(areas_links, areas):
    df = web_scrap(url)
    df.to_csv(name + '.csv')
    print(df)
```

---

Full code

```
# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
#import csv
import re
#import requests
import pandas as pd 
#from IPython import display  

# --- functions ---

def web_scrap(urlpage):
    # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)

    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    # find a string starting from generatechartData
    data = soup.find(string=re.compile('generatechartData()'))

    # finding patter for Price
    pattern = '\r?\ndescription: "([^"]+)"(?:\r?[^()]+)\)'
    rPrices = re.findall(pattern, data) 

    # finding patter for date
    pattern = '\r?(?:\r?\n(?!newDate\.setFullYear\().*)*\r?\nnewDate\.setFullYear\(([^()]+)\);'
    rdates = re.findall(pattern, data)

    # removal of '\n' in the data
    rdates = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in rdates]

    # split dates on Years and Months 
    rYear = [i.split(',')[0] for i in rdates] 
    rMonth = [i.split(',')[1] for i in rdates] 

    # data cleaning on the December. For some reason its '0' instead of '12'
    rMonth = [re.sub(r'\b0\b', '12', i) for i in rMonth]

    #building dataframe for the data
    df = pd.DataFrame({
             'Prices': rPrices,
             'Year': rYear,
             'Month': rMonth
         })

    return df

# --- main ---

areas_links =  ('https://www.morizon.pl/ceny/warszawa/',
      'https://www.morizon.pl/ceny/warszawa/bemowo/')

areas = ('warszawa','bemowo')
    
for url, name in zip(areas_links, areas):
    df = web_scrap(url)
    df.to_csv(name + '.csv')
    print(df)
```